# NSBezierPath on a NSView aren't lining up correctly

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsbezierpath

I have an NSWindow with a NSView (stored in a nib):

[image]

I'm trying to add a BezierPath to a layer for that view (self.view2):

```
CAShapeLayer* circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
[self.view2 setLayer:circleLayer];

circleLayer.fillColor = [NSColor redColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.path = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.view2.bounds].quartzPath;
circleLayer.strokeColor = [NSColor blueColor].CGColor;
circleLayer.strokeStart = 0.0f;
circleLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5f;
circleLayer.lineWidth = 5.0f;
circleLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(135.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

This is what I get back:

[image]

Why isn't the resulting view aligned properly (i.e., top right like it's on my nib)?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that if I resize the main window in any way, the NSView immediately aligns itself in the correct position.

Comment: Is the rotation happening around the bottom left corner of the view?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to put that code inside awakeFromNib() instead of applicationDidFinishLaunching().  Now it works.